# How to calculate date difference for all the rows in a table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a table called `effective`, it has id, start time, end time.

I want to calculate the date difference for all the rows. I've tried like following method,

```
select DATE_PART('hour', age(endtime,starttime )) OVER (PARTITION BY id) as increase from effective
```

But it shows the following error

> ERROR:  OVER specified, but date_part is not a window function nor an aggregate function

I want a result like,

```
id || starttime                 || endtime                       || hour
1  || '2017-09-15 14:50:39.312' || '2017-09-15 16:50:34.349'     || 2
2  || '2017-09-15 14:50:34.349' || '2017-09-15 15:55:48.894319'  || 1
```

Comment: just remove the `over` clause.

Comment: It is violating the syntax as I'm using partition.

Comment: I assume that @VamsiPrabhala meant the entire clause `OVER (PARTITION BY id)` rather than just the word `OVER`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `date_part` and subtract the times.

```
SELECT id, starttime, endtime, date_part('hour',endtime-starttime) AS hour
FROM effective
```

Output

```
id  starttime            endtime              hour
1   2017-09-15T14:50:39Z 2017-09-15T16:50:34Z 1
2   2017-09-15T14:50:34Z 2017-09-15T15:55:48Z 1
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/916ac9/2/0

Also ID 1 start to end is only 1 hour 59 min and 55 seconds, NOT 2 hours.